# use shell script to parse json returned by a restful service

Tags: bash, web-services, shell, scripting

I have a Restful web service with a URL like "http://myhost:5000/getname" to return a JSON string like this: 
`{"firstName": "john", "lastName": "doe"}`

Now that I need to use Linux shell to call the web service and parse the returned JSON string to get the first name and last name. They need to be stored into two variebles and printed out.

I am new to shell scripting, so would some one please kindly share your thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Use `curl` and `jq`.

Comment: Thanks. But jq has to be installed on my ubuntu. Can we just use out-of-box shell-scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet would be to use any json aware tool. However here is solution using `awk` and `eval` , later should be avoided as much as possible.

sample input file:

```
cat file.json
{"firstName": "john", "lastName": "doe"}
```

Solution:

```
eval $(awk 'BEGIN{FS=RS=","} {gsub( /{|}|"/,"");split($0,a,":");print a[1] "="a[2]} ' file.json | tr -d ' ')

echo $firstName
john
echo $lastName
doe
```

OR using `tr` and `xargs`

```
eval $(tr '[[:punct:]]' ' ' < file.json  |tr -s ' ' |xargs -n2 |tr ' ' '=' )
echo $firstName
john
echo $lastName
doe
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at `jq`

```
$ echo '{"firstName": "john", "lastName": "doe"}' | jq '.firstName, .lastName'
"john"
"doe"
```

Comment: Thanks. But jq has to be installed on my ubuntu. Can we just use out-of-box  shell-scripting?

Comment: I advise to parse json (or any kind of structured data like html,xml,etc...) with  a dedicated tool. Using `awk`, `sed` or other is not a good idea to my opinion (especially if you want to do more complex data extraction)