# Bash : check values in file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I try to check the end of my files for error checking. I try to work it by awk, but the values calculated in awk cannot be passed back to my bash.

```
s=0
f=0

for ((i=0;i<num_inf;i++)) do
    ii=${inf[$i]}

    for ((j=0;j<num_gro;j++)) do
        jj=${gro[$j]}

        for ((k=0;k<num_tri;k++)) do
            kk=${tri[$k]}
            awk 'END{x=($2+$8);if($x<10) (( f++ )) ;else (( s++ ))}' $ii/$jj/$kk/out.dat
        done

    printf '%2s' "$s"
    printf '%2s' "$f"
    s=0
    f=0

    done
done
```

The returned s and f are always 0. Since there is an if-else test here, I expect at least one of s, f returns non-zero value.

Does anyone has experience in using awk? I am a beginner in bash and awk. Or anyone has suggestion to bypass awk / has a simpler solution?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: the awk process is run in isolation, so its variables are not visible to bash. have it print the values of `s` and `t` when it hits the end of the file and use `$(` ... `)`  in bash to capture this result.

Comment: If you print a number from awk, that number can be read by your shell script by piping it to read command.

Comment: Since it is a protected environment, I think you can use `eval` like this:

`eval "$(awk 'END{x=($2+$8);if($x<10) echo "((f++))";else echo "((s++))"}' "$ii/$jj/$kk/out.dat")"`

Comment: its possible to get variables out of awk,but should be used only on extream cases : check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385434/use-shell-script-to-parse-json-returned-by-a-restful-service/39385742#39385742

Comment: Get rid of the bash and just do it all in awk, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), but we don't know enough about what you're doing (e.g. the values of your shell variables and array contents) to help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an example of passing variables from `bash` to `awk` and back again:

```
result=$(awk -v f=$f -v s=$s '
  END{x=($2+$8);
  if($x<10) (( f++ ));
  else (( s++ ));
  printf "%d\t%d\n", $f,$s
}' $ii/$jj/$kk/out.dat)
f=$(echo "$result" | cut -f1)
s=$(echo "$result" | cut -f2)
```

Comment: Be careful: the pipe symbol probably means the whole lot is run in a sub-shell and the values read into `f` and `s` are not then available in the main shell.  There are ways to circumvent that (process substitution, `shopt -s lastpipe`, etc).

Comment: oops that's true. "fixed".

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a very clear demonstration for passing values between 'bash' and 'awk'

Answer (score 0):

here's an easier option:

```
x=$(tail -n1 $ii/$jj/$kk/out.dat | awk '{print $2+$8}')
[ "0$x" -lt 10 ] && f=$(expr $f + 1) || s=$(expr $s + 1)
```

explanation:

1. get the last line of this out.dat, add fields 2 & 8, store the result in x.
2. if x < 10, increment f, else increment s

Comment: Thanks for your solution! But mind if you explain [ "0$x" -lt 10 ]? I am trying to learn how it works.

Comment: it's the traditional way of handling the possibility that $x might = "" sometimes. in this case, `[ $x -lt 10 ]` or `[ "$x" -lt 10 ]` would both cause an error, whereas `"0$x"` evaluates to 0, so no error.

Comment: If I understand correctly, when `$x = 10`, `"0$x" = 010` which still works. Just in case `$x = empty space`
Thanks!